# While developing a custom module, which function creates table in database?

Tags: 7, database

While developing a custom module in Drupal 7, which function actually creates tables in the database?

I have implemented `hook_schema` in `mymodule.install`, `mymodule.info`, `mymodule.module` file and defined the Controller class and creates an StdClass object, but still I can't seem to find my tables in my database.

Can anybody tell me what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: did u enable module? can u paste your code?

Comment: `hook_schema` should write only in `.install` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, you are using the correct hook.

If your module is already enabled, then the implementation of `hook_schema()` won't get called.  This is also the case if the module has been enabled, and then disabled without uninstalling.

I would try disabling your module, and then ensuring it is uninstalled by either heading to ***admin/modules/uninstall/*** or (if you have Drush installed) run `drush pm-uninstall mymodule`

From the [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7):

> The tables declared by this hook will be automatically created when
>   the module is first enabled, and removed when the module is
>   uninstalled. This happens before hook_install() is invoked, and after
>   hook_uninstall() is invoked, respectively.

I'm not sure why you'd be defining a controller class though, or even which one you're defining.  Drupal 7 does this with an array, it's not very OO (Drupal 6/7 is array soup).

If this doesn't solve your issue perhaps you could paste a munged version of your implementation of `hook_schema`.